# How to apply 2 shopping cart price rules in magento

Tags: cart, price, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, shopping

I wanted to know that how can i apply 2 shopping cart price rules at the same time. For example i have a coupon which will allow you discount of 15% (any cart amount ). Secondly if the cart total is still more then Rs 750 then we will allow a discount of rs. 50 also. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a shopping cart price rule for `fixed amount discount` having condition of

> subtotal equal or greater than 750

It will be automatically applied when the cart subtotal is equal or more than 750.

Create 2nd shopping cart rule for discount coupon code. And apply that code on shopping cart.

Both the rules will be applied.